# CloudFormation stack stuck in 'Create-In'Progress'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a cloudformation stack, which I am deploying to via my cdk package. My package contains 3 constructs (a Route53 hostedZone, a dnsValidationCertificate, and an IAM role). On a previous account, with the same stack, this took 5 minutes to deploy. However, my stack has been stuck on a 'Create In Progress' state for the past 3 hours, indicating something is definitely wrong. Is there something I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the certificate is stuck in pending state waiting for domain ownership verification.  Are you able to view your stuck stack in the AWS CloudFormation console, check Events, and inspect the Resources created?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/domain-ownership-validation.html

Comment: Yea it turned out that my certificate was stuck in pending state because I had not gotten domain ownership. Right when I added my domain to my Route53, this worked without any issues. Thanks!